# Add field separator and quotes to data exported from mysql via python

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I've written this python script to pull data from a database and it provides me the data I need but I would like the fields to be separated by a command and each row enclosed in double quotes.  For example:

I currently get:

data0 data1 data2 data3

I'd like get:
"data0", "data1", "data2", "data3"

I've tried adding FIELD ENCLOSED BY \" but get the error:
pymssql.OperationalError: (156, "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BY'.DB-Lib error message 156, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n").  Appreciate any help.

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

import pymssql as dbi
from collections import defaultdict

db_h = "1.2.3.4"
db_d = "DB"
db_u = "user"
db_p = "PW"

con = dbi.connect(db_h,db_u,db_p,db_d)
cur = con.cursor()

SQL = ("SELECT data0,data1,data2,data3"
       "FROM mytable")

cur.execute(SQL)
for row in cur.fetchall():
   print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]

cur.close
con.close
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the format I wanted, I used:

```
  NewFile = open(File,'a')
  NewFile.write("\"" + row[0] + "\"" + ", " + "\"" + row[1] + "\"" + ", " + "\"" + row[2] + "\"" + ", " "\"" + row[3] + "\"" + ")\n")
  NewFile.close()
```